# Is there a limit to the length of a rail gun made with permanent magnets?

Tags: magnetic-fields, energy-conservation

Edited Question:  The permanent magnet rail gun depicted at a web site (see original question) is a simple enough device that projects a metal block along a track. Is there some sort of theoretical and practical limit to how long it can be made? 1000 m? 1000 km? 100,000 km?

Question before edit for reference-

> Please see the permanent magnet rail gun depicted [here:][1]
>
> If this actually works,  theoretically the rail could extend around
>   the earth and come back to the starting point, enabling a continuous
>   motion of the projectile until the effect of the magnets wear out.
>
> If it is too difficult to build a rail around the earth,  this
>   experiment could be done using a circular disk in space, with the
>   magnets constrained and travelling around the circumference of the
>   disk.
>
> Momentum and energy will be conserved since the magnets and the
>   projectile will push on the magnets which will push on the railgun
>   attached to the earth, and the earth will experience a minute loss of
>   rotational energy.
>
> [1]: http://www.waynesthisandthat.com/magneticguns.html

Comment: Are you asking if the rail gun depicted can put an object into orbit? Or if some kind of supergun can launch an object into orbit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Newtons Cannon ball problem](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67012).

Comment: Theoretically, one could build a giant collider, like the LHC but, well, waaaaayyyy bigger, that circled the Earth. Simple engineering scale up and all...

Comment: The depicted rail gun uses permanent magnets, and propels the projectile a few metres along the track.  Once it passes the line of magnets it slows down and friction brings the projectile to a stop.  Suppose we were to extend the permanent magnet rail gun to  a length of 1 kilometre to 10 kilometres to 1000 kilometres to finally the circumference of the Earth, would not mean that the projectile will keep moving down the track and circling the Earth without stopping?

Answer (score 0):

There is no technical reason for a limit to the length of the permanent magnet
rail gun, however there may be a limit to the speed the projectile may reach.

There are many such permanent magnet rail guns on the internet. [The site](http://www.waynesthisandthat.com/magneticguns.html) mentioned in the question cautions that careful arrangement of the magnets is necessary for the device to work.

"It is very common for the distances the projectile travels to start decreasing after seven magnet pairs. This is usually caused by the magnet pairs not being perfectly aligned with each other. If one stack is longer than the other, an imbalanced magnetic field results, causing the projectile to lose speed. If the misalignment is more than 1/4 inch the projectile can be captured and come to a complete stop near the end of the bore."

Extending the device indefinitely would result in a long row of magnets which will have to be correctly aligned in order to make the device work. While this is not impossible, it may not be practical.

If the aim is to extend the distance travelled by the projectile, this could be done by arranging for a series of permanent magnet rail guns arranged one after another, so the projectile coming off the previous rail gun will enter the next rail gun, and be speeded up once again. The device may or may not be sensitive to the the exact entry speeds of the projectile. If it is, then the entry speed will have to be  will have to be correctly maintained between limits.

[This answer](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Physics-1358/2012/12/magnet-powered-rail-gun.htm) on the all experts answer site seems to say that the entry speed of the projectile is not critical.

The force on the projectile is matched by an equal on opposite force on the rail gun track.